# error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml, power-platform

I have a very simple Yaml code, I am trying to use and it is causing me so much pain but I cannot see an error besides the one i am getting at the end

```
error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git
[detached HEAD d1f4c36] Work now
```

Here is the code :

```
stages:
- stage : Build

  jobs:
     - job:
       displayName: "Build Ripple 3 dataverse Solution"
       pool :
         vmImage: 'windows-2019'
       variables:
       - group: "Ripple 3 Core"
      
       steps:
       - task: PowerPlatformToolInstaller@2
         inputs:
           DefaultVersion: true
         displayName : "Power Platform Tool Installer"
       
       - task: PowerPlatformExportSolution@2
         inputs:
           authenticationType: 'PowerPlatformSPN'
           PowerPlatformSPN: 'Service Connection'
           SolutionName: '$(PowerPlatformSolution)'
           SolutionOutputFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\$(PowerPlatformSolution).zip'
            
      
       - task: PowerPlatformUnpackSolution@2
         inputs:
           SolutionInputFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\Ripple3Core.zip'
           SolutionTargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(PowerPlatformSolution)_unmanaged'
           
       
       - script: |
           git config user.email  "xx@xx.com"
           git config user.name "Automatic Build"
           git checkout main
           git add --all
           git commit -m "Work now"
           git push origin main
```

Comment: I wonder if you ever could find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
git checkout "main"
```

Also, it may be necessary to checkout before exporting solution :

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/40/z330.png

It is also possible to use Publish artifacts component :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

Git is telling you that it does not recognize 'main' as branch nor file. The branches only exist on remote repository unless you checked them out already.

Instead of

```
git checkout main # there is no local branch called main
```

Try

```
git checkout origin/main
```

Comment: nope exactly the same error : path spec 'origin/main did not match any files known to git

Comment: In that case I would run check if you have git and remote set up correctly. E.g. `git remote show origin` should show you remote branches.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding git fetch before your checkout.

```
git fetch
git checkout main
```

Answer (score 0):

Since September 2022 Azure Pipelines only does a shallow checkout by default so it won't actually know about your tags and branches. If you just do a `git checkout main` or `git checkout "main"` you'll get an error like: `"error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git"`.

If you add a [`checkout` step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) which does a full depth checkout before attempting to interact with the repo you'll be able to do your `git checkout main`, add any commits, and then push your commits/tags.

**Example:**

```
stages:
- stage : Build

  jobs:
     - job:
       displayName: "Build Ripple 3 dataverse Solution"
       pool :
         vmImage: 'windows-2019'
       variables:
       - group: "Ripple 3 Core"
      
       steps:
       - checkout: self
         fetchDepth: 0
         fetchTags: true
         persistCredentials: true

       - task: PowerPlatformToolInstaller@2
         inputs:
           DefaultVersion: true
         displayName : "Power Platform Tool Installer"
       
       - task: PowerPlatformExportSolution@2
         inputs:
           authenticationType: 'PowerPlatformSPN'
           PowerPlatformSPN: 'Service Connection'
           SolutionName: '$(PowerPlatformSolution)'
           SolutionOutputFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\$(PowerPlatformSolution).zip'
            
      
       - task: PowerPlatformUnpackSolution@2
         inputs:
           SolutionInputFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\Ripple3Core.zip'
           SolutionTargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(PowerPlatformSolution)_unmanaged'
           
       
       - script: |
           git config user.email  "xx@xx.com"
           git config user.name "Automatic Build"
           git checkout main
           git add --all
           git commit -m "Work now"
           git push origin main
```